# How to call a stored procedure from MyBatis Java?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, mybatis

I am getting the error:

> org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org. apache. ibatis.          exceptions.PersistenceException:

and

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapped Statements collection does not contain value for .."

when I call stored procedure from mybatis using Java.

I am using *PostgreSQL* as a database and a *Spring MVC* framework. For this, my DAO class calling the stored procedure is:

```
Orders orders=new Orders();
```

Values are set in orders variable programatically.

```
Integer insert= getSqlSession().insert("records",orders);**
```

My mybatis file looks like this:

```
<insert id="records" parameterType="Orders" statementType="CALLABLE">
 {call fn_records_tbl(#{rId,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},#{state,javaType=String,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN},#{uId,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},#{status,javaType=String,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN})}
</insert>
```

My stored procedure syntax is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_records_tbl(rId integer, state character,uId integer, status character)

RETURNS void AS

$BODY$
DECLARE

    -- my code
BEGIN

    -- my code
END

$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;

ALTER FUNCTION fn_records_tbl(integer, character, integer, character)
OWNER TO mydba;
```

and my entity class  for passing parameters is:

```
 public class Orders implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 267216928694677437L;
  private Integer uId;
  private Integer rId;
  private String status;
  private String state;

     // here are my setter and getter
 }
```

Comment: Can you add your mapper code here and give the complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **My syntax for calling stored procedure is correct both in MyBatis and in stored procedure.**

As I am using Spring framework so due to some transitive dependency my stored procedure is not calling from MyBatis in java.

So I checked my pom.xml file for finding transitive dependency and then I exclude all those dependencies for MyBatis and uses the recent version of MyBatis for spring framework.

Now it is working correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am having same issue with MyBatis 3 and Oracle 11g

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your configuration from `insert` to `select`

```
<select id="records" parameterType="Orders" statementType="CALLABLE">
 {call fn_records_tbl(#{rId,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},#{state,javaType=String,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN},#{uId,javaType=Integer,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=IN},#{status,javaType=String,jdbcType=CHAR,mode=IN})}
</select>
```

Comment: That's not the problem,I solve it by changing the version of MyBatis jar.I get recent version of it.